# Не работает синхронизация времени на windows 10

Tags: windows-10, синхронизация, ntp

В моей сети шлюз раздаёт метку времени по NTP протоколу.
Проблемы имеют только компьютеры с Windows10, семёрка без проблем получает время.

В журнале событий windows вот это:

```
Поставщик времени "VMICTimeProvider" указал, что текущее аппаратное обеспечение и 
операционная среда не поддерживаются, и их работа остановлена. Это поведение ожидаемо для 
VMICTimeProvider в средах non-HyperV-guest. Это поведение может быть ожидаемо для 
текущего поставщика в текущей операционной среде.
```

Запускал синхронизацию из командной строки с дебагом,
w32tm /debug /enable /file:c:\temp\ntpDebug.log /size:102400 /entries:0-300
получил это:

```
153303 07:56:55.3274984s - ---------- Log File Opened -----------------
153303 07:56:55.3276116s - RPC Call - Query Configuration
153303 07:56:55.3276646s - RPC Call - Query Provider Configuration
153303 07:56:55.3277008s - TimeProvCommand([NtpClient], TPC_Query) called.
153303 07:56:55.3277387s - RPC Call - Query Provider Configuration
153303 07:56:57.5417844s - RPC Caller is OPC-SERVER\Admins (S-1-5-21-768319367-3470924430-994789215-1008)
153303 07:56:57.5418422s - RPC Call Attribute is local=1, kernel=0, session=0, authentication=6, protocol=2, OpNum=0
153303 07:56:57.5418832s - RPC Call - HardResync
153303 07:56:57.5419151s - W32TmServiceMain: ********** Time Slip Notification **********
153303 07:56:57.5419820s - ClockDispln TimeSlip:TimeSlip LastUTC:764711 SetUnsync: LI:3 S:0 RDl:0 RDs:0 TSF:0x0 
153303 07:56:57.5420428s - TimeProvCommand([NtpClient], TPC_TimeJumped) called.
153303 07:56:57.5420723s - UpdateTimerQueue1: TN:119486090000::: LRT:112765150000  LUT:119486090000 LAFLTNS:0 TSLGT:0 LTNS:864000000000
153303 07:56:57.5420886s - W32TmServiceMain: waiting i16.000s (1024.000s)
153303 07:56:57.5421054s - PeerPollingThread: PeerListUpdated
153303 07:56:57.5421464s - PeerPollingThread: waiting forever
153303 07:57:13.5342316s - W32TmServiceMain: timeout
153303 07:57:13.5343406s - ** NTP sample vector is empty.
153303 07:57:13.5343653s - No new NTP sample is available.
153303 07:57:13.5343978s - UpdateTimerQueue1: TN:119646090000::: LRT:112765150000  LUT:119486090000 LAFLTNS:159922291 TSLGT:159922291 LTNS:864000000000
153303 07:57:13.5344207s - W32TmServiceMain: waiting 1024.000s
```

Такая операция из под администратора тоже не помогла:

```
net stop w32time
w32tm /unregister
w32tm /register
net start w32time
```

w32tm.exe /config /syncfromflags:MANUAL /manualpeerlist:192.168.5.254 /reliable:yes

w32tm.exe /resync

```
153304 07:07:40.5596203s - ---------- Log File Opened -----------------
153304 07:07:40.5597173s - RPC Call - Query Configuration
153304 07:07:40.5597438s - RPC Call - Query Provider Configuration
153304 07:07:40.5597637s - TimeProvCommand([NtpClient], TPC_Query) called.
153304 07:07:40.5597836s - RPC Call - Query Provider Configuration
153304 07:08:25.3960895s - RPC Caller is OPC-SERVER\Admins (S-1-5-21-768319367-3470924430-994789215-1008)
153304 07:08:25.3961491s - RPC Call Attribute is local=1, kernel=0, session=0, authentication=6, protocol=2, OpNum=6
153304 07:08:25.3961907s - RPC Call - Query Status
153304 07:08:35.2757552s - RPC Caller is OPC-SERVER\Admins (S-1-5-21-768319367-3470924430-994789215-1008)
153304 07:08:35.2758178s - RPC Call Attribute is local=1, kernel=0, session=0, authentication=6, protocol=2, OpNum=0
153304 07:08:35.2758600s - RPC Call - HardResync
153304 07:08:35.2758943s - W32TmServiceMain: ********** Time Slip Notification **********
153304 07:08:35.2759678s - ClockDispln TimeSlip:TimeSlip LastUTC:6108661 SetUnsync: LI:0 S:1 RDl:0 RDs:100000000 TSF:0x0 
153304 07:08:35.2762575s - TimeProvCommand([NtpClient], TPC_TimeJumped) called.
153304 07:08:35.2762883s - ClockDispln: we're a reliable time service with no time source: LS: 0, TN: 864000000000, WAIT: 86400000
153304 07:08:35.2763081s - UpdateTimerQueue1: TN:954478280000::: LRT:795161250000  LUT:954478280000 LAFLTNS:0 TSLGT:0 LTNS:864000000000
153304 07:08:35.2763280s - W32TmServiceMain: waiting i16.000s (1024.000s)
153304 07:08:35.2763449s - PeerPollingThread: PeerListUpdated
153304 07:08:35.2763858s - PeerPollingThread: waiting forever
153304 07:08:51.2624645s - W32TmServiceMain: timeout
153304 07:08:51.2625301s - ** NTP sample vector is empty.
153304 07:08:51.2625554s - No new NTP sample is available.
153304 07:08:51.2625892s - UpdateTimerQueue1: TN:954638280000::: LRT:795161250000  LUT:954478280000 LAFLTNS:159861707 TSLGT:159861707 LTNS:864000000000
153304 07:08:51.2626096s - W32TmServiceMain: waiting 1024.000s
153304 07:09:38.0692256s - RPC Caller is OPC-SERVER\Admins (S-1-5-21-768319367-3470924430-994789215-1008)
153304 07:09:38.0693021s - RPC Call Attribute is local=1, kernel=0, session=0, authentication=6, protocol=2, OpNum=0
153304 07:09:38.0693623s - RPC Call - ForceResync
153304 07:09:38.0694051s - W32TmServiceMain: ********** Time Slip Notification **********
153304 07:09:38.0694936s - ClockDispln TimeSlip:TimeSlip LastUTC:6112680 SetUnsync: LI:0 S:1 RDl:0 RDs:100000000 TSF:0x0 
153304 07:09:38.0697574s - TimeProvCommand([NtpClient], TPC_TimeJumped) called.
153304 07:09:38.0697936s - ClockDispln: we're a reliable time service with no time source: LS: 0, TN: 864000000000, WAIT: 86400000
153304 07:09:38.0698195s - UpdateTimerQueue1: TN:955106250000::: LRT:795161250000  LUT:955106250000 LAFLTNS:0 TSLGT:0 LTNS:864000000000
153304 07:09:38.0698466s - W32TmServiceMain: waiting i16.000s (1024.000s)
153304 07:09:38.0698598s - PeerPollingThread: PeerListUpdated
153304 07:09:38.0699098s - PeerPollingThread: waiting forever
153304 07:09:54.0633967s - W32TmServiceMain: timeout
153304 07:09:54.0634665s - ** NTP sample vector is empty.
153304 07:09:54.0634906s - No new NTP sample is available.
153304 07:09:54.0635244s - UpdateTimerQueue1: TN:955266250000::: LRT:795161250000  LUT:955106250000 LAFLTNS:159935899 TSLGT:159935899 LTNS:864000000000
153304 07:09:54.0635454s - W32TmServiceMain: waiting 1024.000s
153304 07:09:54.0655428s - RPC Call - Query provider status
153304 07:09:54.0655916s - TimeProvCommand([NtpClient], TPC_Query) called.
153304 07:09:54.0680221s - W32TimeHandler called: SERVICE_CONTROL_PARAMCHANGE
153304 07:09:54.0681142s - W32TmServiceMain: Param change notification
153304 07:09:54.0682973s - ReadConfig: Found provider 'NtpClient':
153304 07:09:54.0683467s - ReadConfig:   'Enabled'=0x00000001
153304 07:09:54.0683792s - ReadConfig:   'DllName'='C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL'
153304 07:09:54.0684003s - ReadConfig:   'DllName'='C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL'
153304 07:09:54.0684202s - ReadConfig:   'DllName'='C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL'
153304 07:09:54.0684431s - ReadConfig:   'InputProvider'=0x00000001
153304 07:09:54.0684726s - ReadConfig: Found provider 'NtpServer':
153304 07:09:54.0685100s - ReadConfig:   'Enabled'=0x00000000
153304 07:09:54.0685359s - ReadConfig:   'DllName'='C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL'
153304 07:09:54.0685563s - ReadConfig:   'DllName'='C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL'
153304 07:09:54.0685756s - ReadConfig:   'DllName'='C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL'
153304 07:09:54.0685973s - ReadConfig:   'InputProvider'=0x00000000
153304 07:09:54.0686256s - ReadConfig: Found provider 'VMICTimeProvider':
153304 07:09:54.0686617s - ReadConfig:   'Enabled'=0x00000001
153304 07:09:54.0686895s - ReadConfig:   'DllName'='C:\Windows\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll'
153304 07:09:54.0687099s - ReadConfig:   'DllName'='C:\Windows\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll'
153304 07:09:54.0687298s - ReadConfig:   'DllName'='C:\Windows\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll'
153304 07:09:54.0687521s - ReadConfig:   'InputProvider'=0x00000001
153304 07:09:54.0689111s - ReadConfig: 'PhaseCorrectRate'=0x00000001 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0689467s - ReadConfig: 'UpdateInterval'=0x00057E40 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0689695s - ReadConfig: 'FrequencyCorrectRate'=0x00000004 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0689918s - ReadConfig: 'PollAdjustFactor'=0x00000005 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0690147s - ReadConfig: 'LargePhaseOffset'=0x02FAF080 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0690370s - ReadConfig: 'SpikeWatchPeriod'=0x00000384 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0690587s - ReadConfig: 'HoldPeriod'=0x00000005 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0690816s - ReadConfig: 'MinPollInterval'=0x0000000A (2)
153304 07:09:54.0691045s - ReadConfig: 'MaxPollInterval'=0x0000000F (2)
153304 07:09:54.0691280s - ReadConfig: 'ClockHoldoverPeriod'=0x0000C350 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0691515s - ReadConfig: 'AnnounceFlags'=0x00000005 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0691743s - ReadConfig: 'LocalClockDispersion'=0x0000000A (2)
153304 07:09:54.0691984s - ReadConfig: 'MaxNegPhaseCorrection'=0x0000D2F0 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0692219s - ReadConfig: 'MaxPosPhaseCorrection'=0x0000D2F0 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0692448s - ReadConfig: 'EventLogFlags'=0x00000002 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0692677s - ReadConfig: 'MaxAllowedPhaseOffset'=0x00000001 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0692912s - ReadConfig: 'UtilizeSslTimeData'=0x00000001 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0693141s - ReadConfig: 'ClockAdjustmentAuditLimit'=0x00000320 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0693376s - ReadConfig: 'TimeJumpAuditOffset'=0x00007080 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0693623s - Clock adjustment info: dwCurrentSecPerTick: 156247 dwDefaultSecPerTick: 156250 bSyncToCmosDisabled:0
153304 07:09:54.0693815s - PerfFreq:1660152c/s
153304 07:09:54.0694074s -   No params changed for local clock.
153304 07:09:54.0694358s - /--TimeProvider: new enabled provider list
153304 07:09:54.0694580s - | Name:NtpClient, Started:0, Input:1, Marked:0, RefCount:0, DllName:C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL
153304 07:09:54.0694797s - | Name:VMICTimeProvider, Started:0, Input:1, Marked:0, RefCount:0, DllName:C:\Windows\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll
153304 07:09:54.0695972s - >--
153304 07:09:54.0696255s - | Total:2, Input: 2, Marked: 0
153304 07:09:54.0696436s - \--
153304 07:09:54.0696628s - /--TimeProvider: Parameter change before list is updated
153304 07:09:54.0696839s - | Name:NtpClient, Started:1, Input:1, Marked:0, RefCount:0, DllName:C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL
153304 07:09:54.0697020s - >--
153304 07:09:54.0697207s - | Total:1, Input: 1, Marked: 0
153304 07:09:54.0697375s - \--
153304 07:09:54.0697562s - /--TimeProvider: new disabled provider list
153304 07:09:54.0697773s - | Name:NtpServer, Started:0, Input:0, Marked:0, RefCount:0, DllName:C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL
153304 07:09:54.0697948s - >--
153304 07:09:54.0698134s - | Total:1, Input: 0, Marked: 0
153304 07:09:54.0698309s - \--
153304 07:09:54.0698490s - /--TimeProvider: Parameter change before list is updated
153304 07:09:54.0698706s - | Name:NtpServer, Started:0, Input:0, Marked:0, RefCount:0, DllName:C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL
153304 07:09:54.0698887s - >--
153304 07:09:54.0699074s - | Total:1, Input: 0, Marked: 0
153304 07:09:54.0699249s - \--
153304 07:09:54.0699484s - TimeProvCommand([NtpClient], TPC_UpdateConfig) called.
153304 07:09:54.0701056s - ReadConfig: 'AllowNonstandardModeCombinations'=0x00000001 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0701345s - ReadConfig: 'CompatibilityFlags'=0x80000000 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0701586s - ReadConfig: 'SpecialPollInterval'=0x00008000 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0701809s - ReadConfig: 'ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes'=0x0000000F (2)
153304 07:09:54.0702037s - ReadConfig: 'ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes'=0x00000007 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0702266s - ReadConfig: 'EventLogFlags'=0x00000001 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0702495s - ReadConfig: 'LargeSampleSkew'=0x00000003 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0702724s - ReadConfig: 'SignatureAuthAllowed'=0x00000001 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0702965s - ReadConfig: 'Type'=NTP (2)
153304 07:09:54.0703248s - ReadConfig: 'NtpServer'=192.168.5.254,0x9 (2)
153304 07:09:54.0703537s - ReadConfig: 'ManualPeerList'(parsed)='192.168.5.254,0x9'
153304 07:09:54.0703869s - ReadConfig: 'MinPollInterval'=0x0000000A (2)
153304 07:09:54.0704140s - ReadConfig: 'MaxPollInterval'=0x0000000F (2)
153304 07:09:54.0704344s - Poll interval settings: MinPollInterval:10 MaxPollInterval:15
153304 07:09:54.0704573s - NTP client telemetry enabled: 0
153304 07:09:54.0705242s - AddNewPendingPeer: manual
153304 07:09:54.0705465s -   ManualPeerListUpdate: add:1 del:1 noch:0
153304 07:09:54.0705754s - StartListeningThread completed!
153304 07:09:54.0706013s - PeerPollingThread: waiting forever
153304 07:09:54.0706350s - StartPeerPollingThread completed!
153304 07:09:54.0706603s - Starting 'VMICTimeProvider', dll:'C:\Windows\System32\vmictimeprovider.dll'
153304 07:09:54.0706832s - PeerPollingThread: PeerListUpdated
153304 07:09:54.0707356s - PeerPollingThread: waiting forever
153304 07:09:54.0714289s - LoadLibrary
153304 07:09:54.0714837s - Logging Info: Time provider 'VMICTimeProvider' indicated that the current operating environment is unsupported and has stopped. This is expected for VMIC provider in non-Hyperv environments. This may be the expected behavior for the current provider in the current operating environment as well. error:-2147024846
153304 07:09:54.0715921s - Discarding provider 'VMICTimeProvider'.
153304 07:09:54.0716211s - RemoveProviderFromList: VMICTimeProvider
153304 07:09:54.0716415s - /--TimeProvider: Provider list after the provider is actually removed
153304 07:09:54.0716638s - | Name:NtpClient, Started:1, Input:1, Marked:0, RefCount:0, DllName:C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL
153304 07:09:54.0716819s - >--
153304 07:09:54.0717012s - | Total:1, Input: 1, Marked: 0
153304 07:09:54.0717186s - \--
153304 07:09:54.0717385s -   Provider list: 0 stopped, 0 started, 1 not changed.
153304 07:09:54.0717584s - /--TimeProvider: Parameter change after list is updated
153304 07:09:54.0717801s - | Name:NtpClient, Started:1, Input:1, Marked:0, RefCount:0, DllName:C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\w32time.DLL
153304 07:09:54.0717981s - >--
153304 07:09:54.0718228s - | Total:1, Input: 1, Marked: 0
153304 07:09:54.0718445s - \--
153304 07:09:54.0718650s - RPC Call - Query Configuration
153304 07:09:54.0718891s - RPC Call - Query Provider Configuration
153304 07:09:54.0719096s - TimeProvCommand([NtpClient], TPC_Query) called.
153304 07:09:54.0719349s - RPC Call - Query Provider Configuration
153304 07:09:54.0720487s - UpdateTimerQueue1: TN:955266250000::: LRT:795161250000  LUT:955106250000 LAFLTNS:159981864 TSLGT:159981864 LTNS:864000000000
153304 07:09:54.0720704s - W32TmServiceMain: waiting 1023.995s
153304 07:12:30.2831330s - RPC Caller is OPC-SERVER\Admins (S-1-5-21-768319367-3470924430-994789215-1008)
153304 07:12:30.2831933s - RPC Call Attribute is local=1, kernel=0, session=0, authentication=6, protocol=2, OpNum=7
153304 07:12:30.2832366s - RPC Call - Private Log 
153304 07:12:30.2833095s - ---------- Log File Closed -----------------
```

Помогите решить проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть домен(и служба NTP на контроллере настроена и запущена) попробуй так, если домена нет, то убери вторую строку и убери rem вначале третьей.

```
c:\windows\system32\w32tm.exe /register
c:\windows\system32\w32tm.exe /config /syncfromflags:DOMHIER /reliable:yes
rem c:\windows\system32\w32tm.exe /config /syncfromflags:MANUAL /manualpeerlist:ip_gw /reliable:yes
net stop w32time
timeout /T 5
net start w32time
timeout /T 10
c:\windows\system32\w32tm.exe /resync
timeout /T 10
c:\windows\system32\w32tm.exe /resync
```

Проверь статус и источник

```
w32tm /query /status
Индикатор помех: 0(предупреждений нет)
Страта: 4 (вторичная ссылка - синхронизирована с помощью (S)NTP)
Точность: -23 (119.209ns за такт времени)
Задержка корня: 0.2377857s
Дисперсия корня: 0.3558565s
Идентификатор опорного времени: 0x0A071709 (IP-адрес источника:  10.x.x.x)
Время последней успешной синхронизации: 24.09.2020 9:16:35
Источник: DC.FQDN
Интервал опроса: 15 (32768s)
```

Comment: C:\Users\Admins>w32tm /query /status
  Индикатор помех: 0(предупреждений нет)
  Страта: 1 (основная ссылка - синхронизирована по радиочасам)
  Точность: -23 (119.209ns за такт времени)
  Задержка корня: 0.0000000s
  Дисперсия корня: 10.0000000s
  Идентификатор опорного времени: 0x4C4F434C (имя источника:  "LOCL")
  Время последней успешной синхронизации: 25.09.2020 9:44:18
  Источник: Local CMOS Clock
  Интервал опроса: 10 (1024s)

Comment: ты вместо IP_GW укажи ip-адрес или FQDN ntp-сервера в команде. у тебя имя источника  LOCAL в выводе, видишь? значит нтп-сервер не настроен. и используются локальные часы. сделай start/stop/resync. и посмотри что у тебя появится ип адрес источника в  выводе статуса.

Comment: Подправил в сообщении

Comment: Указал вместо ip_gw ip-адрес сервера, синхронизация не заработала, лог добавил в сообщение.

Comment: w32tm /query /status что выводит, по логу не понятно что происходит.